# Default type instances referring to each other

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

Is there a way to have default type instances defined in terms of each other? I'm trying to get something like this working:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
data Tag = A | B | C

class Foo (a :: *) where
    type Bar a (b :: Tag)

    type Bar a A = ()
    type Bar a B = Bar a A
    type Bar a C = Bar a A

instance Foo Int where
    type Bar Int A = Bool

test :: Bar Int B
test = True
```

but this doesn't work:

```
Couldn't match type `Bar Int 'B' with `Bool'
In the expression: True
In an equation for `test': test = True
```

Note that this doesn't work either:

```
test :: Bar Int B
test = ()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, default type instances can be defined in terms of each other (as you can see from your own example):

```
instance Foo Int where
--    So the default recursive definition will be used instead
--    type Bar Int A = Bool

test :: Bar Int B
test = ()
```

However when you redefine associated type synonym in your instance definition for `Int` you replace **entire** default 3-line defintion of `Bar` (and not just the `type Bar a A = ()`) with one line `type Bar Int A = Bool` which means `Bar Int B` and `Bar Int C` are no longer defined.

So I guess one of the ways to use recursive defaults the way you intended is to redefine specific synonyms instead (though it is rather verbose):

```
class Foo (a :: *) where
    type Bar a (b :: Tag)
    type Bar a A = BarA a
    type Bar a B = BarB a

    type BarA a
    type BarA a = ()

    type BarB a
    type BarB a = Bar a A

-- This now works
instance Foo Int where
    type BarA Int = Bool

test :: Bar Int B
test = True
```

Which can fall back to defaults:

```
-- As well as this one
instance Foo Int where
--    type BarA Int = Bool

test :: Bar Int B
test = ()
```